# How to show arraylist data in a textview?

Tags: android

I am new to programming so I am having some problem in my code. My code is giving me an error when I am trying to show the data in `ArrayList` in a `TextView`.

My program should run like this: Every time I click the button it should show the next data in the array.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

import java.util.*;

import static com.example.asadabbas.statusshuffle.R.id.action_bar;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView Status,Show;
Button btn;
ArrayList<String>demo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Status=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Show=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
   demo=new ArrayList<String>();


    demo.add("Iam Feeling lucky");
    demo.add("wow");
    demo.add("Android");
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            for (String d: demo) {
                Show.getText(d);
            }
       }
   });
}



}
```

Comment: Well, can you please show what are those errors? First thing I can see is that you should use setText() instead of getText().

Comment: Show.setText(Show.getText() +d); instead of Show.getText(d); if you will use Show.setText(d); you display just last element

Comment: thanks it was a silly mistake ... but its only showing the last data on the textview . i want it like . that every time i click the button i should show the next value in the array

Comment: i did it  it but now it is showing all the data at once and by clicking same data is being add in the text view

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `Show.setText(d)`.

Moreover, be careful as your `for` loop will make a click always display "Android".

Comment: yeah exactly wt should i do ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to say `Show.setText(demo.get(<whatever you want to get>))`

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a global variable like:

```
int count=0;
```

in ur onCreate() method write like this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

            Show.setText(demo.get(count));
        count++;
     if(count==demo.size){
        count=0;
      }
   }
```

});